# Changing TextView every 5 seconds

Tags: java, android

In my strings.xml I have 5 strings with text. And I want to be able to change the content of a TextView every 5 seconds.

Example:

First 5 seconds the TextView will show the content of the first string, then next five seconds it will show the second string. And after the fifth string it will show the first string again.

Sorry about this bad description, I'm new in Java.

Comment: Implement a Time Listener. From there is is straightforward. If the time from the startup time is a factor of 5 in seconds, change the text. You might want a boolean for changing state.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
final TextView textView = yourTextView;
    final int[] array = {R.string.text1, R.string.text2,R.string.text3,R.string.text4,R.string.text5};
    textView.post(new Runnable() {
        int i = 0;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textView.setText(array[i]);
            i++;
            if (i ==5)
                i = 0;
            textView.postDelayed(this, 5000);
        }
    });
```

Comment: THX, its working, tho I had to change the data type to int.

Comment: Thanks, actualy you right, and you could also use getString(R.string.text) instead

Answer (score 0):

```
new CountDownTimer(25000, 5000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText(//question here);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText(//End of questions);
     }
  }.start();
```

For further Info see this -> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Handler" in this

Create a handler in onCreate

```
     `String[] arr = {R.string.value1, R.string.value2,R.string.value3,R.string.value4,R.string.value5};`
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
```

Now create one Thread and use while loop to periodically perform the task using the sleep method of the thread.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                       textView.setText(arr[i])
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
    }
}).start();
```